useCookies from react-cookies causes rendering loop
I have a code that worked before but after I updated all the libraries, it started to render the App component continuously and React is throwing an Infinite Render Loop error: Minified React error #185
Here is my code:
import React from 'react';
import { CookiesProvider, useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import store from './redux/store';

import { getUserDetailsByToken } from './redux/actions/user-actions';

const AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE = 'authat';

function App(props) {
  const { i18n, userDetailsLoaded } = props;
  const [cookies] = useCookies([AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE]);

  if (cookies[AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE] && !userDetailsLoaded) {
    store.dispatch(getUserDetailsByToken());
  }

  i18n.changeLanguage('en');

  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <main className="app-content full-height">
          ...
        </main>
      </div>
    </CookiesProvider>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    userDetailsLoaded: state.userReducers.userDetailsLoaded,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

I tried to add a flag to only call the store function once considering that the user details gathering will cause the re-render, but did not work.
Also I commented out the whole cookies check without success.
If I try to comment out the line const [cookies] = useCookies([AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE]); and it stopped rendering uncontrollably but that means I would need another way to check the cookies when the application starts.

Both store.dispatch(getUserDetailsByToken()); and i18n.changeLanguage('en'); calls are side effects, and should be part of the render.
When you call store.dispatch(getUserDetailsByToken()); it probably starts a process that causes a re-render, which triggers the dispatch again, and so on...
In addition, you should use the react-redux useDispatch and useSelector hooks, instead of wrapping the component with the connect HoC, and getting dispatch by importing the store.
import React from 'react';
import { CookiesProvider, useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { getUserDetailsByToken } from './redux/actions/user-actions';

const AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE = 'authat';

function App(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userDetailsLoaded = useSelector(state => state.userReducers.userDetailsLoaded);
  const { i18n } = props;
  const [cookies] = useCookies([AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE]);
  
  const authCookie = cookies[AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE];
  
  // an effect that gets called on mount or whenever authCookie or userDetailsLoaded change
  useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies[AUTHENTICATION_COOKIE] && !userDetailsLoaded) {
      dispatch(getUserDetailsByToken());
    }
  }, [dispatch, authCookie, userDetailsLoaded]);

  // a one time effect on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage('en');
  }, []);

  return (
    <CookiesProvider>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <main className="app-content full-height">
          ...
        </main>
      </div>
    </CookiesProvider>
  );
}

export default App;


Thanks you for your response! I tried commenting the whole call to getUserDetailsByToken() and the behavior is the same.
I will try to implement your suggestion with useDispatch and useSelector as it seems like a good idea :) maybe this will also change the behavior.

If you've commented all side effects, and it still re-renders in a loop the problem might be in another place.

I just got to implement your suggestions and it seems that the re-rendering was caused by the line i18n.changeLanguage('en'); . By moving it inside the effect, the page works now :). Thank you verry much for the support.
